# I can't login math exchange using firefox or MS IE

Tags: support, bug, login

I'm using Windows 7. Just uninstalled Google Chrome and installed firefox, but now I can't login.

After Login it seems I logged in already:
[image]

but when it automatically directed to the math exchange page, I'm still not loggin yet....
[image]

what could I do?

Comment: Try clearing the cache of the browser.

Comment: it's a newly installed Firefox. I went to Tools -> Options -> network -> Cached web content -> clear now, still not working.

Answer (score 2):

This happened to me lately.  The following worked for me (Windows 7, Firefox 35.0):

```
Open menu -> Options -> Privacy
```

In the section "History" select "Use custom settings for history," then click on "Show Cookies..."   Look for cookies of StackExchange sites (e.g. math.stackexchange.com) then remove them.

You might want to close Firefox and open it again.  Try logging in.  Does it work now?

Comment: it works like a charm :)

Comment: You might want to accept this answer, then. :)

Comment: I don't know how to login as anonymous now :(

Comment: It's okay. I'm glad your problem is solved. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, Stackexchange has intentionally changed its login procedure so that you now have to delete cookies *every single time you log in*.  This is asking a bit too much, I think.